# Laravel Count Multiple Tables In Eloquent

Tags: laravel, relationship

I am trying to count related tables via model but can't successful.

I have a categories, questions and answers table.

I can count questions related to a category but can't count answers from related categories. U can think its a forum system.

**Category Model**

```php
public function questions(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Question','category_id','id');
}
```

**Question Model**

```php
public function answer()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Answer');
}

public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category','category_id','id');
}
```

**Answer model**

```php
public function question()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Question','question_id','id');
}
```

I can count questions for a related category view Category model like below

```php
public function questioncount(){
    return $this->questions()->where('status',1)->count();
}
```

Tried below for counting answers but no luck;

```php
public function answercount()
{
    return $this->questions()
        ->leftJoin('answers','answers.question_id','=','questions.id')
        ->count();
}
```

Comment: Use `->groupBy('questions.id')` and Try

Comment: Not worked bro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try [Has Many Through](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) relationship.

So let's define a Has Many Through relationship in Category model:

```
class Category
{
    public function answers()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Answer::class, Question::class);
    }
}
```

Then of course you can get the answers count like this:

```
$question->answers()->count();
```

Comment: But i gues i must make relation between answers and categories table. Because there are no relation between categories and answers, only relation between questions - answers and questions - categories isnt it? When i tried your code it gives me Unknown column 'answers.question_answer_category_id error

Comment: ok i figured it out with extra foreign keys in hasthrough relationship thank you bro.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count the number of results from a relationship without actually loading them you may use the withCount method, which will place a {relation}_count column on your resulting models. For example:

```
 $answers = App\Question::withCount('answers')->get();
```